# Auto calculate result in app make in kivy/ python

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language

Is it possible to get an automatic result calculation in kivy? I think that I have 3 TextInput fields and when at least 2 of them are filled in 3 I will get the result.

I think of something like that:

```
--------------
|  2         |  --> TextInput 1
--------------
|result = 5  |  --> TextInput 2
-------------
|    3       |  ---> TextInput 3
--------------

Or

--------------
| result = 5 |  --> TextInput 1
--------------
|     2      |  --> TextInput 2
-------------
|    3       |  ---> TextInput 3
--------------
```

The result should appear automatically after entering at least 2 numbers.

My my.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class CalculatorHome(Screen):
    pass


GUI = Builder.load_file("kv/my.kv")


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
       return GUI

    def change_screen(self, screen_name, direction):
        # Get the screen manager from the kv file
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
        screen_manager.current = screen_name
        screen_manager.transition.direction = direction

    def clear_text(self, *args):
        for ar in args:
            ar.text = ''


MainApp().run()
```

Calculate.kv with TextIput

```
<CalculatorHome>:
    FloatLayout:

        GridLayout:

            rows:3
            pos_hint: {"top": .8, "left": 1 }
            size_hint: 1, .4

            TextInput:
                id: number1
                multiline: False
            TextInput:
                id: number2
                multiline: False
            TextInput:
                id: number3
                multiline: False

        GridLayout:

            rows:1
            pos_hint: {"top": .3, "left": 1 }
            size_hint: 1, .1

            Button:
                text: "CLEAR"
                on_press: app.clear_text(number1, number2, number3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more simple if you put something from kv to python file, like this:

```
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
       # if you use ScreenManager you should return it in build function
       self.sm = ScreenManager()
       # creating the objects of screen classes
       self.homescreen = HomeScreen()
       self.calculatorhome = CalculatorHome()
       # don't forget to set names of screens in kv file!
       self.sm.add_widget(self.homescreen)
       self.sm.add_widget(self.calculatorhome)
       self.t1 = ObjectProperty(None)
       self.t2 = ObjectProperty(None)
       self.t3 = ObjectProperty(None)
       Clock.schedule_once(self.gettextinputs)
       return self.sm

    def gettextinputs(self, *args):
        # get textinputs from kv
        self.t1 = self.calculatorhome.ids.number1
        self.t2 = self.calculatorhome.ids.number2
        self.t3 = self.calculatorhome.ids.number3

        # bind on change function calling
        self.t1.bind(text = lambda e1, e2: self.checkinputs())
        self.t2.bind(text = lambda e1, e2: self.checkinputs())
        self.t3.bind(text = lambda e1, e2: self.checkinputs())

    def checkinputs(self):
        if self.t1.text and self.t2.text:
            result = int(self.t1.text) + int(self.t2.text)
            self.t3.text = str(result)
        elif self.t1.text and self.t3.text:
            result = int(self.t1.text) + int(self.t3.text)
            self.t2.text = str(result)
        elif self.t2.text and self.t3.text:
            result = int(self.t2.text) + int(self.t3.text)   
            self.t1.text = str(result)
```

So now when you change text of your textinputs the empty one will show the result of others two.

Comment: Method `gettextinputs()` and `checkinputs()` should not be in class `MainApp()`?

Comment: @piotr_python of course they should, it's my mistake, answer's edited

Comment: The next problem is: `self.t1 = self.calculatorhome.ids.number1
 AttributeError: 'MainApp' object has no attribute 'calculatorhome'` 
Should you add `self`to `calculatorhome`?

Comment: @piotr_python yes, check my answer again, I added it there

Comment: I added another 'self' and  now i have problem with my old method  change_screen():    `screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
 KeyError: 'screen_manager'`

Comment: @piotr_python yes, now it's defined in MainApp class. So from there you can use `self.sm.current = 'calculator'`. But you should give names to your screens in kv file like `name: 'calculator'` or in py file when you create objects like `self.calculatorhome = CalculatorHome(name='calculator')`

Comment: Ok, i done it, but now i get a error: `text = text.replace(u'\r\n', u'\n')
 AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: I corrected the solution so that it works on numbers(int).   shouldn't assign numerica values to the text, even if it doesn't break right then